# how to force execution of requests inside async.each with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, async.js, requestjs

I have a async.each that iterates an array and for every element inside the array it execute a function "check" that has a request inside. This is the code but when I run it I see from the debugger that node doesn't execute the check function and it block its execution.

```
async.each(array,
  function(v_page, callback){
    if(v_page.url.length>=5){
      internals.check(v_page.url,array2, function (body) {
        callback();
      });
    }
  },
  function(err){
    internals.calls(var1,var2,var3);
});
```

I tried with a normal for loop but it jump at the internals.calls function without execute the internals.check function for the async nature of node. So how can i force the execution of the check function?

This is the code of the check function:

```
internals.check = (url,array2,cb) => {
  request(url, function(err, recordset) {
    if(err){
      cb(array2);
    }else {
      //some stuffs
      cb(array2)
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You call `callback` only when `v_page.url.length >= 5`, but you need to do that for each element:

```
async.each(array, function(v_page, callback) {
 if(v_page.url.length >= 5) {
   internals.check(v_page.url,array2, function(body) {
     callback();
   });
 } else {
   callback(); <== call callback here, when condition is not met
 }
 ...
```

Another problem is that, you incorrectly call callback in `internals.check`. According Node.js notation, the first parameter of callback must be an error or null (async uses this notation). But in your case you call callback with `array2` anyway:

```
internals.check = (url, array2, cb) => {
  request(url, function(err, recordset) {
    if (err) {
      cb(err); // <== pass error here
    } else {
      cb(null, array2); // <== no error, so first parameter is null, the second is data
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I added it but nothing changed and above all I did not solve the problem... It doesn't execute the check function.

Comment: Updated the answer, you have a bug in `internals.check` function.

Comment: ok I fix the callback bug but from the debugger i saw that it enters inside the check function and when it arrives to request, it jump to the end of the function so it doesn't see the callback cb. I think that this is the problem.

Comment: Of course `it jumps` to the end, because request is `asynchronous_ function, it returns immediately and later, when data is loaded, calls callback.

Comment: so there isn't any solution?

Comment: Tell me what doesn't work exactly? I fixed all found bugs.